# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined помогите исправить ошибку

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo, warning

делаю вывод товаров по категориям,но возникает ошибка

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: 
>   parameter was not defined in 
>   C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\diplom\Models\ProductModel.php on line 21
>   Буду рада,если поможете решить проблему новичку( если и сам вывод товаров не рабочий,то буду рада критике и советам) :)
>   ProductController.php

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{


public function products($idcat){


$stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name,price,description  FROM products WHERE category_id = ?");
$stmt->bindParam('i',$idcat);
$stmt ->execute();
$result = array();
$i=1;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $result[$i]['name']=$row['name'];
    $result[$i]['description']=$row['descriprion'];
    $result[$i]['price']=$row['price'];
    $i++;
}
return $result;

}

}
```

ProductController.php

```
require_once (MODEL_PATH ."/CategoryModel.php");
class ProductController extends Controller
{
private $pageTpl = "/Views/templates/product.tpl.php";
public function __construct()
{
    $this->model=new ProductModel();
    $this->view= new View();
}
public function index(){
    $this->pageData['title']="О нас";

    $category=CategoryModel::Get_Category();
    $this->pageData['category'] = $category;
   $idcat=$category['id_category'] ;
    $this->pageData['products']=$this->model->products($idcat);

    $this->view->render($this->pageTpl,$this->pageData);
    }
}
```

и на всякий CategoryModel.php

```
class CategoryModel extends Model {


public  static function Get_Category (){
    $conn=DB::connToDB();
    $sql="SELECT id, name FROM categories";
    $result = array();
    $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $i=1;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
        $result[$i]['name']=$row['name'];


        $i++;
    }

    return $result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного недочитали PDO, вы в запросе использовали плейсхолдер `?`, а потом пытались биндить `name parameter` `i` которого у вас нет, если хотите через `name parameter` запрос должен быть такой:

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name,price,description  FROM products WHERE category_id = :i");
$stmt->bindParam('i',$idcat);
$stmt ->execute();
```

Если же через плейсхолдер, то такой:

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name,price,description  FROM products WHERE category_id = ?");
$stmt ->execute(array($idcat));
```

Comment: Оу, я видимо,где-то неправильную информацию вычитала ,что  execute() для числовых лучше не использовать, а с bindParam() действительно промахнулась)  Спасибо большое, помогло))))